# Tag Inbox by Gmail reminders?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Is there any add on or hack that would allow tagging Inbox by Gmail reminders?

Comment: You'll have much more success with your question if you focus on describing the problem you're trying to solve rather asking if there's a tool that does what you want.

Comment: See also: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

Inbox by Gmail doesn't support add-ons at this time.

Regarding reminders hacks, you could set reminders in email messages and Google Keep notes both of them allow to be labeled. I.E. send an email to yourself, assign to it the labels that you want then set a reminder. In Google Keep just create a note, add labels to it an the desired reminder.

From the reference

> ## View Google Keep reminders in Inbox
>
> You can view reminders you created
>   in Google Keep in Inbox by Gmail.
>
> From Inbox, you can Snooze your reminder to a different time or
>   location [image: Snooze]. You can also mark it done [image: Mark done].
>
> The title of the reminder is based on the title and body of the note
>   in Google Keep. To view or edit the note, click the Open in Google
>   Keep link under the reminder.
>
> Learn more about [reminders in Google Keep](https://support.google.com/keep/answer/3187168).

---

**References**
[Reminders - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6062813?hl=en)

Comment: I tried setting Google Keep reminders but I don't see them on my Inbox by Gmail?

Comment: @Eliyahu. I updated the answer.